# Grey tiles Android Google Maps emulator

Tags: android, maps, emulation, tiles

First question.

When I build the app in android emulator instead of showing up a Map of Google Maps, it shows the empty grey tiles.

Things I've done:

- I added the Google API Sdk.
- The project target is Android + Google APIs (Google Apis).
- I created a new emulator with target Google Apis, with GPS, and incremented the RAM and the max vm application heap to 512 and 48.
- I deleted debug.keystore and default.keyset 2000 times and rebuild the key and sent to Google 2000 times more and still doesn't work.
- My command to get the SHA1 is as follows:

  ./keytool.exe -list -v -keystore /home/q/my_name/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Then I get the sha1 and paste in google and add a semicolon and the application name, so:

```
E4:A ..... C38;com.example.myappname
```

Ok, then my code:

main activity:

```
package com.example.rest;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Rest extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rest);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_rest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Rest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rest" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyAdh38-k34RPi7aQ4ik6ExKKWI-wS-bDJA"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Important things:

- The prebuilt maps application WORKS.
- The sdk example (com.example.android.apis.MapsDemo) DOESN'T WORK, BECAUSE SHOWS GREY TILES TOO.

Any clues? Ask me whatever you need about my question and I'll answer.

(I've edited app name and some things to not show real data about my name, etc..)

Logcat:

```
01-15 10:47:11.498: W/KeyCharacterMap(509): No keyboard for id 0
01-15 10:47:11.498: W/KeyCharacterMap(509): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-15 10:47:17.938: W/System.err(509): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down.
01-15 10:47:18.068: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:284)
01-15 10:47:18.068: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:238)
01-15 10:47:18.068: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:175)
01-15 10:47:18.068: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:325)
01-15 10:47:18.078: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-15 10:47:18.078: W/System.err(509):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-15 10:47:18.298: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:246)
01-15 10:47:18.298: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:129)
01-15 10:47:18.308: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:189)
01-15 10:47:18.308: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:242)
01-15 10:47:18.334: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.getResponse(AndroidHttpConnectionFactory.java:132)
01-15 10:47:18.334: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.openDataInputStream(AndroidHttpConnectionFactory.java:153)
01-15 10:47:18.348: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:922)
01-15 10:47:18.472: W/System.err(509):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
01-15 10:47:18.472: W/System.err(509):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-15 10:47:19.038: W/MapActivity(509): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@405e68e8
01-15 10:47:19.058: V/MapActivity(509): Recycling map object.
01-15 10:47:19.418: I/MapActivity(509): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
01-15 10:47:19.418: E/MapActivity(509): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

I'm on Linux, but I'm using the keytool.exe that is located on a winxp partition. I don't know if this can cause problems. But keytool.exe gives me the sha1 without problems, I just mention in case it is important.

EDIT: **PROBLEM SOLVED! THE CORRECT ANSWER IS BY FIDO**, JUST SCROLL DOWN YOUR SCREEN.

Comment: I created a key with debug.keystore and it worked perfect so maybe some problem with the key

Comment: Thanks Hari, but did again and doesn't work.

Comment: use this code after setcontentview mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        mv.setSatellite(true);
        mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc = mv.getController();

Comment: Used that code with no success. I can see the zoom controls however, but grey tiles. The last line, mc=... I commented out, because, what type is mc? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @user1979938 Accept Fido answer by ticking the checkmark below the voting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using key of google map V2 for an google map V1 project. Try [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey) to get key for google map V1

Comment: I don't think so, In google apis services I only can activate "Google Maps Android API v2". However I tried exactly your command (in the link) and get only and MD5, when I tried to use it in Google Apis it told me "Your input is invalid". Thanks anyways for your time and patience.

Comment: @user1979938 Post your MD5 key in here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup (end of page) :)

Comment: What do you think that was happening?

Comment: @user1979938 if worked then accepted my answer. I've sucessfully installed V1 and V2, so i can see your problem.

Comment: EDIT: OK, i think i've accepted it :) If I must do anything else, please ask. ("It's my first time here, how do I accept your anwser? I clicked "yes" on "was this post useful to you?" but how do I close the whole question now?")

Comment: @user1979938 You can accept by click in check icon under downvote. If your problem solved then you don't need to to anything

Comment: @user1979938 Google API v1 and v2 is two different API. As Fido stated, you are trying to use API V2 with Map API V1 in your code.